# Will an old (bad) post affect the reputation later?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, down-votes

Just consider the (general) scenario:

- A new enthusiastic user joins [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) and asks a question.
- It isn't a very good one, so it naturally gets a lot of downvotes (around 3-4).
- Now, the reputation of the user stays at `1` and the user realizes his(/her) mistake.
- The user *doesn't* delete the post, and it stays there (it *isn't* deleted by anyone).
- Meanwhile, the user posts a good question/answer which brings in a lot of upvotes.

Now, my questions are:

> - Will the old undeleted post reduce the earned reputation of the user (or will it remain constant at the reputation earned by the new post)?
> - Will further downvotes to the old post affect the repuation?

---

PS: This is just an example of what I mean! :-(

Comment: A bad post will probably be closed soon and nobody cares about it in the future and it gets deleted sooner or later. And a downvote is only 2 rep points.

Comment: @juergend Yes, yes, I _know_ it's not possible.

Comment: @hims056 maybe ur right... might as well delete it right away. :)

Comment: @ambigram_maker - It's not impossible for any closed question to remain undeleted after getting downvotes.

Comment: @hims056 Alright, alright... i need to delete it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the old undeleted post reduce the earned reputation of the user (or will it remain constant at the reputation earned by the new post)?

No. If the user receives downvotes when he has 1 rep, his rep won't be affected when he receives upvotes later.

> Will further downvotes to the old post affect the repuation?

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Any subsequent downvotes will affect reputation normally (-2).

The only restriction is that the reputation does not go below 1. So, downvotes cast during the time the rep is at 1, will not affect reputation at a later time.